# Raspberry Pi Christmas give-away! Participate now!

Tags: discussion

The Raspberry Pi elves have been working hard this Christmas, and to celebrate the festivities (and the graduation!) we're going to be **giving away** **a Raspberry Pi** to **five** of this years most revered community members!

In order to choose the lucky winners of this fabulous Raspberry flavoured treat, we'll be hosting a little competition to find the most sweet toothed of you all.

---

The competition will have five categories, and voting will decide which Raspberry Pi enthusiast is the winner of each. So without further ado...

### 1. [Best new user of 2015](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/658/40)!

We've always tried our best to be welcoming, lets say a big thank you to the best new user of the year!

### 2. [Best overlooked question](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/659/40).

There are always good questions that somehow go unmentioned! Dig up those unanswered questions and reward their contribution!

### 3. [Best community contributor](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/660/40).

Stack Exchange isn't just about questions and answers, who has contributed the most to the community?

### 4. [Best original Raspberry Pi project idea](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/661/40).

We love to hear about your projects! But which is the most ambitious, exciting, or downright crazy?!

### 5.... RNG!

Are you feeling lucky?! One random active user will also have the chance!

---

However the moderator elections go, we want to say thanks to all of you for making it this far. This couldn't have happened without dedicated and enthusiastic users.

Together we look forward to the future! Good luck everyone!

Love *"The Raspberry Pi Pro-tem Moderation team"*

Comment: Jivings, **awesome**. I don't know how to give my words enough weight, but thanks for all the dedication and the effort put to the site to make it through graduation!

Comment: Thanks @Ghanima, but I'm trying to say it's as much the community as it is any individuals :) We couldn't have done it without you and everyone else. Congrats to all!!

Comment: Sure, and that's by extension always the highly dedicated individuals too.

Comment: Just wanted to give another THANKS to @Jivings for the prize ... received it today, all's well. Now off to find a good use for it (shouldn't be a problem :) ).

Comment: @PhilB. You're very welcome :) Thanks for being an outstanding member of the community!

Answer (score 6):

**... and the winners are:**

(votes per 31st December 00:00 UTC)

### 1. [Best new user of 2015](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/658/40)!

**Phil_B (5)**

Runner-ups: SlySven (4), PatrickCook (3), PandaLion98 (0)

### 2. [Best overlooked question](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/659/40).

**ppumkin**

### 3. [Best community contributor](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/660/40).

**Joan (8)**

Runner-up: Ghanima (7)

*Please note that this price will be donated to contributors to our upcoming blog - conditions are to be posted any time soon.*

### 4. [Best original Raspberry Pi project idea](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/661/40).

**PatrickCook with project Nano (13)**

Runner-ups: Jacobm001 (7), SlySven (6), Phil_B (5), VeggieVampire (0)

### 5.... RNG!

*to be announced*

The proud and lucky winners will be contacted as soon as referee @Jivings is available again.

Comment: Thanks for doing this :) I'm back now!

Comment: If any of us can help you, just say the word.

Comment: Yaaaaay! Congratulations to everybody!

Comment: Just received my prize in the post! Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickCook, well then get the project started ;)

Answer (score 1):

### FAQ

- Which model are they?!?

  Plain old *Model B* Pis. No Raspberry Pi Zeros around yet I'm afraid!
- What else do I get?!

  Greedy! Well ask and you shall receive! We also have 5 [pibow cases](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pibow+case&tbm=isch) to go alongside! I'm also going to try and get some swag that comes with the new site makeover ;)
- How do I enter?

  You must be nominated for one of the categories by another community member. You can chat about nominations in [The Bakery](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery) though!
- Is every one eligible?

  Everyone! Except the mod team of course.
- When is the deadline?

  The deadline is the end of the year! **31st December 00:00 UTC**.

---

Oh, and here they are :)

[image]

Comment: Jivings, *that's a model B!*

Comment: ... @goldilocks Oh yeah! :)

Comment: Raspberry Pi 1 Model B Revision 2 to be exact.

Comment: Given the [current Mod elections](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) when is the closing / eligibility deciding  date - so those who lose in that could still get a consolation prize from this! 8-P

Comment: @SlySven I'll still leave the competition open to new moderators :)

Comment: Is this still open?

Comment: @PandaLion98, I was thinking the same thing this morning. Jivings, you better put a dead line on this one. Maybe it will motivate people to nominate and vote in a final rush.

Comment: I nominate myself as the... best new user... *sigh*.

Comment: @PandaLion98 You joined in 2015? Your summary reads "Member for 1 year" so one cannot know.

Comment: I'm actually going away for a couple of weeks, so I wouldn't be able to post them off until half way through January. But lets close the voting at midnight NYE :)

Comment: UTC? Honolulu? Or anywhere on earth ;)

Comment: @Ghanima UTC :)

Comment: @PandaLion98, no self-nominations, that's what jivings said (I tried to nominate myself in the RNG category ;) - didn't work out)

Comment: @Ghanima Teehee

Comment: @PandaLion98, you can motivate others to nominate you. See you in the [Bakery](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery). Oh, see you're already there.

Comment: @Ghanima I think that PandaLion98 joined in Mar 2015 (that was when the [reputation graph](http://stackexchange.com/users/4943099/pandalion98?tab=reputation) starts with 11 on 2015-03-20).

Comment: @SlySven, I am not sure about reputation graphs, actually it shows march for me too. The profile page reads one year (whatever that means). However I will not be nitpicking here. Go ahead and nominate him...