# Christmas give-away - Best new user of 2015!

Tags: discussion

Nominations for the [Christmas give-away](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/654/raspberry-pi-christmas-give-away/657#657) entry number 1!

We've always tried our best to be welcoming, let's say a big thank you to the best new user of the year!

Comment: "Closed as primarily opinion-based" - Really? I guess the standard wording IS unfortunate and that there is no better close reason to use! Is there not a "Lock" Moderator action or will that hide it as well? I guess we just need to wait until the "Answer" is selected? 8-P

Answer (score 5):

I nominate [@Phil_B](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/29174/phil-b).

Answer (score 4):

I nominate [@SlySven](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/36970/slysven) - a "top 2% this quarter" user, albeit he joined just a month ago.

Comment: If I am selected for this "prestigious" award I will use the device (or rather swap out an existing and slightly damaged unit that is the same Model B) and use one of them for a (potentially damaging) test to help answer a [question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40003/resetting-the-pis-main-power-supply-polyfuse-faster) that needs some real hardware (and a domestic freezer!)...

Answer (score 3):

I nominate [@PatrickCook](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/33979/patrick-cook) - another highly active "top 2% this quarter" user.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be worthwhile to nominate [@PandaLion98](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/24224/pandalion98), who it has been reasonably determined does look to have been active since March 2015 - though their Silver Yearling Badge (awarded 2015-12-13) may cloud the issue unless a Moderator can clear this up...