# Christmas give-away - Best overlooked question

Tags: discussion

Nominations for the [Christmas give-away](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/654/raspberry-pi-christmas-give-away) entry number 2!

---

There are always good questions that somehow go unmentioned! Dig up those unanswered questions and reward their contribution!

Comment: Sorry, not sure if you looking for well answered, but marked as unansered, or questions that had no answers but look good?

Comment: @ppumkin I think it's questions that were really good (in some way), but either didn't get enough attention to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 3):

One very early day question that is still left as unanswered.

[How do I supply power through the GPIO?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/how-do-i-supply-power-through-the-gpio/1618#1618)

Another early question day and still hot topic

[How can I stream H.264 video from the Raspberry Pi camera module via a web server?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/how-can-i-stream-h-264-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module-via-a-web-serve/7615#7615)

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a great example of excellent contribution that needs attention

[Can a Raspberry Pi be used to create a backup of itself?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself/5431#5431)

Comment: You have to be joking (assuming you refer to the "answer" this link points to). The question is good, as are some of the other answers, but the "script" is just `dd` with some waffle around it. I was mislead by all the waffle thinking this was a script to address the question when I first started.

Answer (score 0):

This has allot of attention and is a nice oldie. It really has no "proper answer" as its to broad and the original poster seems to be MIA.

[Connect Pi to an old laptop screen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/848/connect-pi-to-an-old-laptop-screen)