# Christmas give-away - Best community contributor

Tags: discussion

Nominations for the [Christmas give-away](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/654/40) entry number 3!

---

Stack Exchange isn't just about questions and answers, who has contributed the most to the community?

Answer (score 8):

I nominate [@joan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/13650/joan) for an incredible amount of high-quality answers given and an even more tremendous quantity of comments to inquire additional info and provide clarification. (... and also for pigpio).

Comment: I second that, Joan's contributions and willingness to help far surpass mine. I wonder if she is really a robot; because she must never sleep.

Comment: Yea, definitely outstanding! contributor in such a short time.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to nominate @Ghanima.  He very clearly cares about this site; to the point where he's willing to run as a moderator.  That speaks volumes to his commitment.

Comment: Another prime example of outstanding contributor in a short time!