# What is the link to the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange Blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

I believe that there is a Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange Blog but am unable to find the URL link to access it.  Does anyone happen to know the URL to access it?

Comment: There's a big graphical link to the blog that should cycle through the (very large) right hand sidebar ads.  Depending on your rep level this may be polluted by the usual type stuff, but beyond that it should almost exclusively be things from [this list](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/704/community-promotion-ads-2016), which is only four items.

Answer (score 6):

The blog address is here:

https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/

You'll find more information in the other meta questions tagged [blog](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog), particularly this one: [We Started a Blog!](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/755/we-started-a-blog?cb=1)

The current "Editor in Chief" is [Jacobm001](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/8496/jacobm001?tab=profile), and he can hopefully be reached via the [blog chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36995/piversify-blog) (unless he is busy with MI6 -- note the "001" and the "air of mystery" in his profile).

Answer (score 1):

As long as the meta post referring to the blog is tagged *featured* it should also show up in the nice box on the right side on the main page: **Featured on meta**.

[image]

Comment: I think what confuses me is that we have a "Featured on meta" ... and article that says "We started a blog" ... but following that, it was hard to find the actual blog itself as opposed to just meta discussion about the blog.

Comment: But the link to the blog is in the first paragraph. While you're right that it might be somewhat hidden there we are using all the possibilities to point to the blog that StackExchange has to offer. Obviously those means are limited (meta post, community add, related chat room). So any ideas how to improve its proliferation are highly welcome. Spread the word!

Comment: Now ... please don't get mad at me ... but I had a question related to the Raspberry Pi ... "Where can I find the awesome blog on Pi based articles hosted by stack exchange?" ... and I posted that as a question in our Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange ... with my thinking that if I want Pi Answers I go to stack exchange ... and that post (the question at the start) was moved to meta.  Would the question of "Where is the blog" not be a relevant question to leave in the primary Q&A as opposed to meta?

Comment: @Kolban Not really.  This is the purpose of meta; if we *don't* do this, then we might as well move all "meta" type questions to the main site and not have meta...at which point we might as well eschew Stack Exchange and create an independent site...and which point the question of who "we" might be becomes a more serious question.  I didn't design the interface here, and even after at least 1-2 thousand hours of use I still have issues with it.

Comment: However, like any piece of software, it's a matter of learning how it does and doesn't work, and certain things assume a minimum level of competence from the user.  I don't know how long I'd been a user before I became aware of the existence and significance of "meta", despite the fact that is pretty obvious if you click the far left entry on the top menubar. So, like any piece of software, if you want to get the most out of it, you read the documentation (which is easy enough to find, and clearly indicated to everyone when they sign up *if they are paying attention*). An aspect of design..

Comment: ..is the balance between complexity and simplicity and depending on the level of genius behind it, lol, there's bound to be a trade off.  At the point where you say, "Even a 5 year old kid could master this in a few hours", you are probably talking about something that doesn't do much.  I think S.E. has evolved through feedback from high frequency regular users, and so tends to target them.  It's like an IDE -- when you first open it up, the basic things you expect may be fairly obvious, figuring the rest out may take some time and effort, and to some extent you get out what you put in.