# Raspberry Pi give-away - blog participation

Tags: discussion, announcement

As you're all aware - [We Started a Blog!](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/755/we-started-a-blog) and to stimulate community contributions we will be giving one shiny Raspberry Pi away*.

Eligible for nomination are contributions within the next three months. So all community posts on the blog that are **published before June 13th** will be in the selection for *most popular blog article*. Don't wait, write an interesting blog post now. See above linked instructions how to submit.

Members of the editoral board are of course not eligible (sorry, Jacob).

---

**How to submit**

- use Github (*highly preferred*), see here: [How to submit an article to the blog](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/761/19949)
- send an email to rpise@emaildodo.com; please use an easily accessible file format, e.g. plain text, rtf, or [github flavoured md](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5922882/3984613)

---

<sup>* While it's technically a leftover from the [Christmas Giveaway](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/654/raspberry-pi-christmas-give-away-participate-now) the Pi is fresh and new.</sup>

Comment: Well, better get started on my Nano repository...