# Blog contribution give-away - call for vote

Tags: discussion, announcement

As outlined [here](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/759/19949) we want to give away a nice Pi2 for the *most popular blog article*. Nominated are all* community** contributions published before June 13th - listed for your convenient voting as answers below. Deadline for voting is June 27th, 00:00 UTC.

No matter who wins, keep reading *and* writing articles for our [blog](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/755/19949). Thank you all for contributing.

---

<sup><sub>* The article [Camera Module Part 1: Getting started](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/143828902324/camera-module-part-1-getting-started) was withdrawn from the poll as requested by author. ** Contributions of the editors of the blog and moderators of the site are not eligible.</sub></sup>

Comment: Why are some of the below linked and others not?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I don't get what you mean.

Comment: The Brown One with Setting up a LAMP stack on a Raspberry Pi - Part 1 below does not have a link to the post

Comment: @SteveRobillard it does (at my end).

Comment: You are right it is a link, but the text formatting is not red like the others. Which is why I didn't think it was a link.

Comment: @SteveRobillard for me all links on meta are grey and thus nearly indistinguishable from text.

Comment: It works in the preview but not if I save the change. So I rolled back my attempt to fix it.

Comment: For me, meta links are orange.

Answer (score 4):

PM with [Exploring the 3.3V Power Rail](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/144555785379/exploring-the-33v-power-rail)

Answer (score 2):

The Brown One with [Setting up a LAMP stack on a Raspberry Pi  Part 1](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/144922590364/setting-up-a-lamp-stack-on-a-raspberry-pi-part-1)